# How to get the content of iframe using jQuery or C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have this code in an iframe:

**HTML CODE**

```
  <iframe id="iframe">
     .......
     <div id="message-box" class="error">
       No flights found
     </div>
     .......
  </iframe>
```

I want to run a JavaScript function when the iframe completely loads and get this inner div and its text. How can I do that?

Here is some code:

**JS CODE**

```
  var content = $("#iframe").contents().find("#message-box").html();
```

[image: error images click here]

Comment: What have you already tried? Please post your code.

Comment: Is your iframe from another domain? if it is then you can't access to the iframe's content. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: take the snap of page translate the png to text using occilator then get the required text i have solution to your defination wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your code. But if you have an iframe with "**iframe**" id, try this;

```
var content = $('#iframe #message-box').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `#` character in your selector. Try replace your code with this:

```
var content = $("#iframe").contents().find("#message-box").html(); // # added
```

Comment: call that function when iframe loads commpltely or after 10 sec of complete page loadx